# @media print query with CSS crashed my printer

Tags: css, media-queries, forms

I've got an online submit to email form, but some people may want to just print the page. I used the @media print query with CSS and when I tried to print the page my printer printed a couple lines and then stopped. It said "unable to send data to printer". Should I try something else entirely or is there a way to make this work? There is JavaScript validation but the page prints okay if I don't try to adjust the styles, so I don't think that's a factor. Without any adjustments it takes two pages to print and doesn't look fantastic.

This is my CSS:

```
@media print {   
    .online {
        display: none;
    }
    .print {
        display: block;
    }
    .container {
        min-height: 0px;
    }
    .content {
        min-height: 0px;
        border: none;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                box-shadow: none;
    }
    nav {
        display: none;
    }
    .dance h3 {
        color: black;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .contact {
        padding: 20px 0 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: none;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .item-bid {
        margin-bottom: 30px;  
    }
    fieldset {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    label {
        font-size: 12px; 
    } 
    input, textarea {
        display: none;
    }
    form p {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .description {
        padding-bottom: 100px;  
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel really silly 'cause it's working now and I didn't change anything!

Comment: Did you, by any chance, reboot any of the involved hardware?

Comment: I did. A couple of times. I think what worked was turning off both the computer and the printer at the same time. I'm not really sure. I wasn't very methodical about it. But at least I know my markup is good. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome you might want to output a PDF via the printing dialog box, and see if there any noticeable errors.